# Trying to understand has_many :through relationship accessing the rows of objects with associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The model relationships are as follows

user model `has_many :pics, dependent: :destroy`

pic model `belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :user_id`

pic model `has_many :pic_tags, dependent: :destroy`

pic model `has_many :tags, through: :pic_tags`

I am trying to pass an instance pic variable that display pics that only have a certain tag from the controller to the view.

tags table

```
  create_table "tags", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "category"
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

pics table

```
  create_table "pics", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "picture"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "caption"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.boolean  "hidden"
  end
```

pic tags

```
  create_table "pic_tags", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "pic_id"
    t.integer  "tag_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

The through relationship is throwing me off. In rails console I am trying to do something like this

```
User.last.pics
```

brings out

```
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` ORDER BY `users`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  Pic Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `pics`.* FROM `pics` WHERE (`pics`.`hidden` IS NULL OR `pics`.`hidden` = 0) AND `pics`.`user_id` = 32 ORDER BY `pics`.`id` DESC
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Pic id: 12, picture: "fb9ba77d7b8756f1bbff_jobs-jpg.jpg", user_id: 32, title: "Test Pic 1 ", caption: "Test Pic 1 ", created_at: "2014-09-15 19:17:38", updated_at: "2014-09-15 19:17:38", hidden: nil>]>
```

but if I do

```
User.last.pics.tags
```

I am getting no method error

```
NoMethodError:   Pic Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `pics`.* FROM `pics` WHERE (`pics`.`hidden` IS NULL OR `pics`.`hidden` = 0) AND `pics`.`user_id` = 32 ORDER BY `pics`.`id` DESC
undefined method `tags' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_Pic:0x007fb50334b5d8>
```

I do this

```
PicTag.find(16)
```

I find the pic id = 12

```
  PicTag Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `pic_tags`.* FROM `pic_tags` WHERE `pic_tags`.`id` = 16 LIMIT 1
 => #<PicTag id: 16, pic_id: 12, tag_id: 1, created_at: "2014-09-15 19:17:38", updated_at: "2014-09-15 19:17:38">
```

with the tag_id set to 1

tag id = 1 is this

```
2.0.0-p247 :050 > Tag.find(1)
  Tag Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `tags`.* FROM `tags` WHERE `tags`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
 => #<Tag id: 1, category: "Length", name: "brown", created_at: "2014-09-12 16:42:58", updated_at: "2014-09-12 16:42:58">
```

so why can't I do this?

```
 User.last.pics.tags
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `User.last.pics` is not a single `Pic` object, it is a collection of `Pic` objects. The `.tags` method only works when called on a single `Pic` object not an entire collection. You will need to look into the `joins` method for further help. Something along of the lines of `User.last.pics.joins(:tags)` will get you closer.